# Clicking off div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a "pop-up" div go away when the user clicks off it. This snippet on my button works just fine:

```
$("#download-1").on("click", function () {
      $("#popupDiv").toggle("slow");
  });
```

The problem is, you can only make the popup div go away when clicking the button.  I've tried using the following snippet to make the div go away anytime you click out of it - but its not working.  Can someone explain why?

```
if ($("#popupDiv").attr("display") == "block") {
      $(":not(#popupDiv)").click(function () {
          $("#popupDiv").toggle("slow");
      });
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="button" id="download-1">
  <img src="Images/Download.svg" />
  </div>
  <div class="popupDiv" id="popupDiv">
      <div class="popup-levels"></div>
      </div>
   <div class="download-type-picker"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Post your html.

Comment: When you pop-up the window, add transparent element in the background and bind the event listener to it.  `$(":not(#popupDiv)").click()` - this is scary, you might not realize it, but that way, you are putting event listener or every single HTML DOM element, that is not #popupDiv! and these won't die out as the overlay element, that will get removed.

Comment: The code is not complete, there's no buttons nor images.

Answer (score 3):

This is the easy solution. You can try it.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){

  var container = $("#popupDiv");//your popupDiv id
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){
    container.hide();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic but if you want to click anywhere outside the popup to make it disappear, you can attach a click event to the `document`. See basic code snippet here:

```
$(document).click(e => {
    // hide popup
});

$(".popup").click(e => {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops propagation to the document click
    // show popup
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('*').click(function(e){
   if(e.target.id == popupDiv || $(e.target).closest('#popupDiv').lenght > 0)
   return;
else
   $("#popupDiv").toggle("slow");
```

Comment: this gives me creeps TBH `$('*').click()`

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of answers, but i'll just show you how i'd choose to do it. Might not be the best practice, but it's my preferred way to do this stuff.

https://jsfiddle.net/twk81but/3/

html

```
<span class="trigger">Hey, trigger me!</span>
```

Js

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
  $("body").append("<div class='popUp'>Well hello There</div><div class='overlay'></div>");
  $(".overlay, .possibleCloseBtn").click(function() {
    $(".popUp, .overlay").remove();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.popUp {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #CCC;
  z-index: 99;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 98;
}
```

Comment: @ab3d_work thanks, i mean it's not looking very elegant, but in comparison to the most upvoted answer - this one won't fire the function everytime "mouseup" on whole document is triggered and the event listeners get cleared from memory the moment the elements are removed (at least AFAIK in most modern browsers)